# unset a specific node inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, simplexml

I am totally stuck here.

I have a simple xml structure in PHP

```
<InvoiceLines>
<InvoiceLine>
    <SalesInvoiceProductLine>
        <ProductIdentifier type="customer">4867895346</ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductName>a name</ProductName>
        <ProductUnitPrice type="net">75</ProductUnitPrice>
        <ProductVatPercentage vatcode="KOMY">24</ProductVatPercentage>
        <SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>1</SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>
        <Dimension>
            <DimensionName>Kustannuspaikka</DimensionName>
            <DimensionItem>110 Tukkukauppa kotimaa</DimensionItem>
        </Dimension>
    </SalesInvoiceProductLine>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
    <SalesInvoiceProductLine>
        <ProductIdentifier type="customer">1345573456</ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductName>name</ProductName>
        <ProductUnitPrice type="net">31</ProductUnitPrice>
        <ProductVatPercentage vatcode="KOMY">24</ProductVatPercentage>
        <SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>1</SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>
        <Dimension>
            <DimensionName>Kustannuspaikka</DimensionName>
            <DimensionItem>150</DimensionItem>
        </Dimension>
    </SalesInvoiceProductLine>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
    <SalesInvoiceProductLine>
        <ProductIdentifier type="customer">Shipping_cost</ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductName>Shipping</ProductName>
        <ProductUnitPrice type="net">0</ProductUnitPrice>
        <ProductVatPercentage vatcode="KOMY">24</ProductVatPercentage>
        <SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>1</SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>
        <SalesInvoiceProductLineDiscountPercentage>0</SalesInvoiceProductLineDiscountPercentage>
    </SalesInvoiceProductLine>
</InvoiceLine>
```

I need to remove the InvoiceLine with the Shipping costs. I have tried a lot (just counting the whole thing, remove the last, different approaches with xPath etc.)

My code at the moment

```
//remove shipping lines, always 0 and not needed
foreach ($base->SalesInvoice->InvoiceLines->InvoiceLine as $key => $invoiceline) {
  if ($invoiceline->SalesInvoiceProductLine->ProductIdentifier == "Shipping_cost") {
echo "shipping cost FOUND \n";
echo "\n";
var_dump($key);
echo "\n";
    unset($base->SalesInvoice->InvoiceLines->InvoiceLine[$key]);
  }
}
```

I can't get my head around this. It finds the shipping cost, but can't get the unset to work. The $key variable holds just a string(11) "InvoiceLine". I have tried many more approaches, but none I got so far that it actually found the correct element.

If there is any information needed, please let me know!

Comment: How exactly did you determine that it did not work?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with xml, you are probably better off utilizing xpath. Something along the lines of:

```
dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$targets = $xpath->query('//ProductIdentifier[text()="Shipping_cost"]');

foreach ($targets as $target) {
    $target->parentNode->removeChild($target);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

That should get you the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

You can save index of the *InvoiceLine* and remove it from the *base->InvoiceLine* array at the end. I changed a little your code to run in my system.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$myXMLData =
'<InvoiceLines>
<InvoiceLine>
    <SalesInvoiceProductLine>
        <ProductIdentifier type="customer">4867895346</ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductName>a name</ProductName>
        <ProductUnitPrice type="net">75</ProductUnitPrice>
        <ProductVatPercentage vatcode="KOMY">24</ProductVatPercentage>
        <SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>1</SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>
        <Dimension>
            <DimensionName>Kustannuspaikka</DimensionName>
            <DimensionItem>110 Tukkukauppa kotimaa</DimensionItem>
        </Dimension>
    </SalesInvoiceProductLine>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
    <SalesInvoiceProductLine>
        <ProductIdentifier type="customer">1345573456</ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductName>name</ProductName>
        <ProductUnitPrice type="net">31</ProductUnitPrice>
        <ProductVatPercentage vatcode="KOMY">24</ProductVatPercentage>
        <SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>1</SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>
        <Dimension>
            <DimensionName>Kustannuspaikka</DimensionName>
            <DimensionItem>150</DimensionItem>
        </Dimension>
    </SalesInvoiceProductLine>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
    <SalesInvoiceProductLine>
        <ProductIdentifier type="customer">Shipping_cost</ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductName>Shipping</ProductName>
        <ProductUnitPrice type="net">0</ProductUnitPrice>
        <ProductVatPercentage vatcode="KOMY">24</ProductVatPercentage>
        <SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>1</SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>
        <SalesInvoiceProductLineDiscountPercentage>0</SalesInvoiceProductLineDiscountPercentage>
    </SalesInvoiceProductLine>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
    <SalesInvoiceProductLine>
        <ProductIdentifier type="customer">222222222</ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductName>name</ProductName>
        <ProductUnitPrice type="net">31</ProductUnitPrice>
        <ProductVatPercentage vatcode="KOMY">24</ProductVatPercentage>
        <SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>1</SalesInvoiceProductLineQuantity>
        <Dimension>
            <DimensionName>Kustannuspaikka</DimensionName>
            <DimensionItem>150</DimensionItem>
        </Dimension>
    </SalesInvoiceProductLine>
</InvoiceLine>
</InvoiceLines>';

$base=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData);
print_r($base);
echo "<br>------------------------<br>";
$indexes = array();
$i = 0;
//remove shipping lines, always 0 and not needed
foreach ($base->InvoiceLine as $key) {
    echo "***".$key->SalesInvoiceProductLine->ProductIdentifier."==="."<br>";
    
    if ($key->SalesInvoiceProductLine->ProductIdentifier == "Shipping_cost") {
        echo "shipping cost FOUND \n";
        echo "\n";
        var_dump($key);
        echo "\n";
        array_push($indexes, $i);
    }
    
    $i++;
}

foreach($indexes as $index) {
    unset($base->InvoiceLine[$index]);
}

echo "<br>------------------------<br>";
print_r($base);
echo "<br>------------------------<br>";
foreach ($base->InvoiceLine as $key) {
    echo "***".$key->SalesInvoiceProductLine->ProductIdentifier."==="."<br>";    
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```